# Example of data access in java or a similar lang

Tags: java, database, flat-file, data-access

Can someone post or point out an example of

1. how flat-file data access is done in java? What java technology is used for the purpose?
2. how rdbms data access is done in java? What java technology is used for the purpose?

Comment: This question is too generic: what do you call data? How is it supposed to be encoded? etc etc

Comment: Sorry for being too generic, but really speaking I'm quite new to all this and honestly I'm not aware of all the details and nitty-gritty. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. java.io is used to read and write data to files. There are several good tutorials online such as [this one](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/index.html) and [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) that will assist you with understanding the details.
2. JDBC is used to connect to databases. Again there are numerous [JDBC tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) online.

Comment: Thank You! That clears up my doubt!

Answer (score 1):

> how flat-file data access is done in java? What java technology is used for the purpose?

As fge said, too generic. Need more detail. You use [File I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) to interact with the file system, but if you need to interact with some specific format, that's just the beginning.

> how rdbms data access is done in java? What java technology is used for the purpose?

With [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html). You can find a driver for just about any database out there along with a horde of supporting libraries to simplify database access, transaction management, schema management, etc.

Answer (score 1):

May I direct you to the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)? In particular the sections [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) and [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)?

Comment: How many answers do we really need linking to the same two tutorials?

Comment: As many as needed to get the point across ;-) Seriously: Didn't see you linked to the same tutorials. Was that an edit? I could have sworn the File I/O link wasn't there when I started digging up the links.

Comment: heh :) Yeah, the file link was an afterthought, since I thought maybe the OP was just looking for plain file access.